# Who should own directories in Applications?

Tags: macos, applications, permission

What are the correct default owner and permission settings for directories in Applications?

For me most are either `Rax admin` (me; sometimes `Rax staff`) or `root  wheel`. The latter permissions are almost exclusively associated with apps installed by the App Store; but I have a few exceptions that, mostly for apps that were originally installed long ago. That seems like a security issue. Should the owner for all non-Apple application directories be me (`Rax admin` or `Rax staff`; does it matter which)? Should the owner for all Apple application directories be `root  wheel`?

Who should own directories in Applications?

Comment: Basically you shouldn't mess with permissions there. If you have and things are acting strange you can run this command in Terminal: **diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`**

Comment: @SteveChambers: Nothing's acting strange. The issue is that root permissions are required by the occasional app in order to update, which is a security risk that really shouldn't, I think, ever be necessary. If an app (other than one maintained by the App Store) really needs root to update, it probably should be removed completely, no?